# Buscando Dados em database Sqlite com php

Tags: php, aplicação-web, sqlite, sqlite3

Estou tentando pegar o nome da minha session, e buscar na database os dados de quem tem este nome, mas o echo nao retorna absolutamente nada.

```
$nome = $_SESSION["Aluno"];


$results = $db->query('Select * from alunos where nome = $nome ');
while($row = $results->fetchArray()){
$row = (object) $row;
echo $row->nome."   /   ";
echo $row->disciplina."   / ";
echo $row->faltas." /  ";
echo $row->nota."     <br> ";
echo "----------"."<br>";

}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Primeiro, você consegue imprimir a variável `$nome`? Caso não consiga, troque `$_SESSION["Aluno"];` para `$_SESSION['Aluno'];`(Aspas simples). Segundo, você startou o `session_start();`? Terceiro, você consegue puxar os dados "manualmente" do banco? A conexão está correta e funcionando?

Comment: Sim , eu consigo imprimir $nome, e se eu trocar $nome por "teste", que seria a minha session , na parte do select, a rotina funciona normalmente e os dados sao imprimidos na pagina.
O banco de dados esta funcionando e a session tambem, so nao consigo puchar os dados passando a variavel no select

Comment: Mas você consegue imprimir a própria `$_SESSION["Aluno"]` ?

Comment: Sim, consigo, acabei de testar.